# How to call an API within ajax call of another API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get weather data from a weather API. This API requires the longitude and latitudes of a location. As I want to use the location name (insted of latitude and longitude) as an user input I want to get those values with a geocode API first.

But when I try to call the weather API within the ajax request of the geocode API I get a cross-origin error.

Here is the code:

```
function get_gps_weather(location,maps_api_key, weather_api_key){

$.ajax({
    url : 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+location+'&key='+api_key,
    type: 'GET',
    success : function(data){
        var latitude=data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
        var longitude=data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];

        $.ajax({
            url : 'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/'+weather_api_key+'/'+latitude+','+longitude
            type: 'GET',
            success : function(weather_data){
                console.log(weather_data)
            }
        });       
    }
}); 
}
```

Thanks,
Lukas

Comment: What is the specific error?

Comment: A cross-origin error has nothing to do with your nested ajax calls. I see no problem in how you nested them. Try debugging each ajax call on their own, a cross-origin error comes when the server you are fetching does not responds with a cross-origin header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code makes sense. The problem you're experiencing is [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Darksky API does not have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` resolving to `*`. This means you will need to set up a proxy server to make calls to the API behind the scenes (Where the request you make sends up your API secret key along side).

https://darksky.net/dev/docs/faq has all the relevant information.

Comment: Thanks, I should have read the instructions ;) Can you tell me how to set up a proxy server on localhost for testing?

Comment: A proxy server is just like any other server, the only difference is that your second request is made to this server (which then makes it to the URL provided in the mentioned request - along with the API key). It depends on the language you want, if JavaScript - use node. Express is a nice library - https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html